# Can I install Lync 2010 SDK with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, lync-2010, lync-client-sdk

I am trying to use the Lync API but our company currently has Lync 2010 and we develop using VS 2013.  When I attempt to install the 2010 SDK it says I need Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or higher and won't let me continue. Obviously I can't install 2008 SP1 since I have VS 2013, so the SDK install doesn't think I have the proper requirements.

Is it possible to install Lync 2010 SDK with VS 2013? If so, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in installing VS2010, then Lync 2010 SDK.
Afterwards I uninstalled VS2010 with all additional components.
So I could compile my project with VS2013.

It is not a very comfortable way but I did not find any other one to install the SDK. You can extract the .exe but there is no installer etc.